# Send data to JS when PHP is told to do so

Tags: javascript, php

Here's an example. One user connects to the website and does some stuff. JS sends changes to PHP and it's processed. Say another user that connected at the same time needs to be notified of this change. So PHP somehow tells the second users browser through JS or something to change some HTML to the second user is aware of said changes. Is there a way I can do this? Or is it a no can do?

Comment: You need Websockets or AJAX. Searching for those terms should get you started; feel free to ask a more detailed question if you need help with something specific.

Comment: Yeah. Got it. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that would be done with Ajax or WEbSockets. 
WebSocket works by opening a connection channel between the server and users.
you can find some websocket Examples Here:
http://www.websocket.org/demos.html

Comment: Cool! WebSockets was the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need websocket (http://socketo.me/) to do that or use pusher (https://pusher.com/) to push something to client.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "POST",
    data: params,
    success: success(){},
    error: error()
});
```